# Executing registered task in kotlin build file

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to convert a gradle build script, which is written in Groovy, into Kotlin. The problem is, that in the Groovy build file in one task another task, which was defined before, is executed. However, it appears that in Kotlin there is no support for that, at least I could not find any in the API.

I have studied the API and searched for similar problems, but I could not find anything useful.

The Groovy code looks like this:

```
task doSomething () {
   ...
}
task anotherTask () {
   ...
   doSomething.execute()
   ...
}
```

How would this call be translated into Kotlin?

```
doSomething.execute()
```

Comment: The method `execute` is not available in Gradle anymore (since 5.0), so this is not caused by a difference between Groovy and Kotlin. It is often found in older builds, but should actually never be used, because it may interfere with the Gradle task execution system.

Answer (score 4):

You should *never* call `execute()` on a task.  Instead set the inputs, outputs and dependencies correctly, and Gradle will call the task for you if it needs to.

something like:

```
tasks {
    val doSomething by registering {
        doLast {
            println("running doSomething")
        }
    }

    val anotherTask by registering {
        dependsOn(doSomething)
        doLast {
             println("Running anotherTask")
        } 
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$ gradle anotherTask

> Task :doSomething
running doSomething

> Task :anotherTask
Running anotherTask

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 746ms
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin is statically typed. So you must know the type of the task of `doSomething` and `anotherTask` if Kotlin not able to infer it for you. `execute` leads me to believe it some sort of execute task. So for your example:

```
val doSomething = tasks.register("doSomething", JavaExec::class.java) {
    main = "com.example.Example"
}

val anotherTask = tasks.register("anotherTask") {
    doSomething.get().exec()
}
```

However, it looks you just want to execute `doSomething` before `anotherTask`, so you'd want:

```
val doSomething = tasks.register("doSomething", JavaExec::class.java) {
    main = "com.example.Example"
}

val anotherTask = tasks.register("anotherTask") {
    dependsOn(doSomething)
}
```

Without knowing the types of your task it's difficult to give you the right answer.